# Multiple sites with Proftpd Vhosts on the same port 21?

Tags: proftpd

I would like to create 2 ftp sites using Proftpd virtual hosts on the same port 21 :

ftp.domain.com : Anonymous access

ftp2.domain.com  : with users and passwords access

Can somebody please tell me the big steps to follow without the details as I would like to know only the big steps to make sure it will work ?

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible without multiple IP addresses, as the FTP protocol does not send the host name during the connection process. See [ProFTPD's documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Vhost.html) on virtual hosting.

Comment: FYI, with [RFC 7151](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7151), FTP now supports the `HOST` command, for providing the host name at connection time, for support just name-based vhosting.